# Titan -- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - creating relationship

Tags: java, titan, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to create relationships in titan and trying to give an array with the properties at creation.

```
while (startNode.hasNext())
        {
            Vertex tempVertex = startNode.next();
            while (endNode.hasNext())
            {
                tempVertex.addEdge(storage.getId(), endNode.next(), keyValue);
            }
        }
```

But it's throwing the following error on edge creation.

```
int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : storage.getProperties().entrySet())
        {
            keyValue[i] = entry.getKey();
            keyValue[i + 1] = entry.getValue();
            i += 2;
        }
```

Normally the map should have the string at every even index already.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided key/value array must have a String or T on even array indices
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element$Exceptions.providedKeyValuesMustHaveALegalKeyOnEvenIndices(Element.java:129)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.ElementHelper.legalPropertyKeyValueArray(ElementHelper.java:117)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.util.ElementHelper.attachProperties(ElementHelper.java:46)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.addEdge(AbstractVertex.java:151)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.addEdge(AbstractVertex.java:23)
    at main.java.com.bag.server.database.TitanDatabaseAccess.applyCreate(TitanDatabaseAccess.java:469)
    at main.java.com.bag.operations.CreateOperation.apply(CreateOperation.java:36)
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.executeCommit(TestServer.java:190)
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.appExecuteBatch(TestServer.java:138)
    at bftsmart.tom.server.defaultservices.DefaultRecoverable.executeBatch(DefaultRecoverable.java:87)
    at bftsmart.tom.server.defaultservices.DefaultRecoverable.executeBatch(DefaultRecoverable.java:68)
    at bftsmart.tom.ServiceReplica.receiveMessages(ServiceReplica.java:432)
    at bftsmart.tom.core.DeliveryThread.deliverMessages(DeliveryThread.java:293)
    at bftsmart.tom.core.DeliveryThread.run(DeliveryThread.java:225)
```

Comment: What is the class type for `keyValue` in the second code block? You didn't show how it is being initialized. Is the code being run in Groovy or Java?

Comment: Do you have `null` values as keys at the end of the `keyValue` array?

Comment: It's java code. keyValue is an Object[]. No I insert Strings and objects only. No null values.

Comment: Yes, but when you create the array you must initialize it to a certain length. If the length of the array is greater than `2 * storage.getProperties().entrySet().size()` then you end up with null values in the array.

Comment: I'll edit the whole code.

Comment: Editing the code I found the error thanks, I inserted some null values.